# Determining why a class-level field is not recreated after a new object is made

Tags: java, selenium, constructor

I have a web page (call it InfoPage) I am processing using Java and Selenium.  The page consists of sections (with names) and fields underneath with values.  See example

```
**Addresses**
    Service Address  616 Anywhere Street
    Notice Account   867-5309
    Service City     Springfield
```

"Addresses" is the section name, and "Service Address", "Notice Account", "Service City" are field names.  and things like "616 Anywhere Street" etc are the values.

The fields under the section are as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>Service Address</td>
  <td>
    <div> 616 Anywhere Street
...
```

I wrote a method to take the section name and field name and get the value there.  This works fine.  There are hundreds of these (above was just a small cross section).  I go through the sections, find the name, and then do a find underneath for the field name.

To avoid having to do this each time, I made a map (class level).

```
static void Map<String, String> fieldmap = new HashMap<>();
```

the key is a concatenation of the section and field name.  When I want to get the value of a field, I first check the map.  If it is empty, then I fill it first.

There is an edit button to edit the fields.  When you edit the fields you can change the values and click save.  I noticed after doing this, when I tried to get a string value it was the old value not the updated one.  I figured "oh, the Map should not be static.  So I removed the static.  However, that did not fix the problem.

It is my belief that each time a new InfoPage is made, the Map should be recreated as empty but that does not seem to be working.

What happens when you do an edit and a save, it does the following (returning an InfoPage):

```
protected static <T> T getPage(WebDriver driver, Class<T> proxy) {
    T t = null;

    try {
        t = PageFactory.initElements(driver, proxy);
        ...
        return t;
```

So I am guessing that an initElements does NOT do a new on the page?  It is defined as

```
public static <T> T initElements(WebDriver driver, Class<T> pageClassToProxy) {
   T page = instantiatePage(driver, pageClassToProxy);
   initElements(driver, page);
   return page;
 }
```

which eventually does a pageClassToProxy.newInstance() which I would guess does a new, which should call the constructor and reinitialize everything.  So I do not understand why after all this happens, my fieldMap still has entries in it.  I removed the static part.

So I guess two questions. First, why is a new fieldMap not being made?  Secondly, is there a way, then, to tell when the page is "dirty"?  That is, the page has changed since the last time I created the map, so I can clear it and fill it again?

Comment: Are u sure u r using the new instance created from the getPage() method? Can u add the calling code also?

Comment: I should be able to add it.  Not sure what is company proprietary

Comment: yeah.  (note the actual names of the objects is diff):   detailPage = editPage.save();

Comment: Tried it with some code and it works as expected. The fields are reinitialized.

Comment: something weird on my end.  Well now in the original edit method I clear the map

Comment: (bandaid solution)